# Efficiently generate JSON summary from numpy distance matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a distance matrix stored as a 2-dimensional numpy array. I am looking for an efficient way to extract a summary containing details of the closest n matches, for each user in the population. This summary will eventually be served as JSON, so I am looking to have it in nested list/dictionary form (example output a little further down).

The following minimal example (5 x 5 distance matrix) demonstrates what I am working with:

```
[[       inf 0.30330249 0.41690763 0.11468943 0.27026611]
 [0.30330249        inf 0.72021012 0.41799192 0.5735686 ]
 [0.41690763 0.72021012        inf 0.3022182  0.14664152]
 [0.11468943 0.41799192 0.3022182         inf 0.15557668]
 [0.27026611 0.5735686  0.14664152 0.15557668        inf]]
```

Assume that we also have access to a list of labels corresponding to the rows/columns of the distance matrix. The code to generate this example distance matrix `dm` and the labels `users` is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform, pdist

n = 5  # Population size
np.random.seed(1)
users = ['User {}'.format(i) for i in range(1, n+1)]
dm = squareform(pdist(np.random.random((n, 1))))
np.fill_diagonal(dm, np.inf)
```

Let's say that we want to find the closest 2 matches per user. From looking at the distance matrix, we can see that for 'User 1', their closest matches are 'User 4' (`0.11468943`) then 'User 5' (`0.27026611`). My desired output is as follows:

```
{
    "User 1": [
        {
            "Main": "User 1",
            "Other": "User 4",
            "Distance": 0.11468943207073423
        },
        {
            "Main": "User 1",
            "Other": "User 5",
            "Distance": 0.27026611388546096
        }
    ],
    "User 2": [
        # redacted
    ],
    "User 3": [
        # redacted
    ],
    "User 4": [
        # redacted
    ],
    "User 5": [
        {
            "Main": "User 5",
            "Other": "User 3",
            "Distance": 0.14664151599976816
        },
        {
            "Main": "User 5",
            "Other": "User 4",
            "Distance": 0.15557668181472672
        }
    ]
}
```

(I realise that the `"Main"` keys above are a bit redundant, I included them to make the data easier to work with on the front-end)

I was able to achieve the desired results using the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

n_per_user = 2  # Number of closest users to find per user

# Get row-wise indices of n smallest distances
indices = np.argpartition(dm, range(n_per_user), axis=1)[:, :n_per_user]

# Each of these comprehensions is for one column of the DataFrame which will be built shortly
users_main = (user for user in users for i in range(n_per_user))
users_other = (users[i] for i in indices.flatten())
distances = (dm[i, j] for i, row in enumerate(indices) for j in row)

# Construct the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(users_main, users_other, distances)), columns=['Main', 'Other', 'Distance'])

#      Main   Other  Distance
# 0  User 1  User 4  0.114689
# 1  User 1  User 5  0.270266
# 2  User 2  User 1  0.303302
# 3  User 2  User 4  0.417992
# 4  User 3  User 5  0.146642
# 5  User 3  User 4  0.302218
# 6  User 4  User 1  0.114689
# 7  User 4  User 5  0.155577
# 8  User 5  User 3  0.146642
# 9  User 5  User 4  0.155577

results = {x: y.to_dict('records') for x, y in df.groupby('Main', sort=False)}
```

This works well for tiny datasets like this, but my real `dm` is 10k x 10k rather than 5 x 5, and I want top 25 per user rather than top 2 (an appropriately sized example can be generated by setting `n` to `10000` and `n_per_user` to `25` in the above code).

The entire program in its current state runs in about 10 seconds on my machine, with the very last step (converting DataFrame to nested dictionary) taking over half of that time. Given that I would like for these steps to be executed very frequently in the final application, I am looking for a more efficient solution. I realise that I could have just asked for help on this last step since it's the one causing the bottleneck, but I suspect there may be better solutions which bypass the need to create a DataFrame altogether, which is why I included so much context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here as after sleeping on it I came up with a solution to go directly from the generators to the dictionary, bypassing the need for a DataFrame. The last two lines of my original code can be replaced with the following for a ~20x speed increase:

```
from collections import defaultdict

results = defaultdict(list)
for main, other, distance in zip(users_main, users_other, distances):
    results[main].append({"Main": main, "Other": other, "Distance": distance})
```